# Css e javascript de bloqueio

Tags: javascript, css, seo, blogger

Eu testei meu blogger no pagespeed e apareceu para bloquer css e javascript de bloqueio e como exemplo ela me deu os seguintes arquios no qual eu devo bloquear:

css:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Qwigley&subset=latin   (e mais de 20 outras fonts diferentes)

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/…t-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

https://www.blogger.com/…s/548467171-widget_css_mobile_bundle.css
http://www.google.com/uds/css/gsearch.css´ 

https://www.blogger.com/…&zx=4116a2a2-4edb-4562-bcdf-ddb8eeb43b48
```

script:

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
http://www.nomedoblog.com/…json-in-script&callback=showrecentposts1
```

Os tutoriais que tem aqui não servem pra estes casos e os arquivos são extremamente necessários, será que uma tag style ou script  e tirar os arquios externos ajudaria?

Comment: Não há nada a fazer se precisar mesmo de importar os ficheiros aí, pode reduzir o numero de ficheiros, juntando todos os css/js só num ficheiro, mas ele vai sempre dar esse aviso. Pode testar isso com a própria página developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed lá no site, até dão esse aviso acerca da própria pag de test

Comment: Olá, olha só, estava vendo a mesma coisa que você e acabei encontrando [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QisqYBIrsdo&t=627s) no youtube.
Talvez possa te ajuda.